# Find real error cause when acquiring connection with c3po ComboPooledDataSource

Tags: java, jdbc, c3p0

I am trying to **get connection** from [ComboPooledDataSource](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSource.html), but let's say I made a **typo in the password**. I would like to get the information about the **actual error cause**, but all I can from the thrown exception is that something went wrong. Is there a way to find out what the real problem is, in form of a String that can be **displayed to the user**?

I am using **c3po-0.9.1.2**.

Let's be concrete, my code looks like this:

```
ComboPooledDataSource ds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
ds.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver");
ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db");
ds.setUser("user1");
ds.setPassword("wrong-password");

try {
    Connection c = ds.getConnection();
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The `ds.getConnection()` code throws an exception, which prints the following stakctrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at test.ConnectionErrorDemo.main(ConnectionErrorDemo.java:21)
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 2 more
```

So, this exception is not helpful at all, as it does not say anything about the actual cause of the problem. However, in the console you can also see log entries like this, which describe the actual problem:

```
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@249939c3 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "user1"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:398)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

If I understand that correctly, this log entry is done by the c3po library itself, an therefore I thought maybe there is a way to access this information somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no specific log that C3p0 generates as far as I know. Refer http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_logging. You just have to enable logging for the C3p0 which you have already done.

Comment: if you want access to the Exception you are seeing logged programmatically, you have is via the `getLastAcquisitionFailureDefaultUser()` and `getLastAcquisitionFailure(java.lang.String username, java.lang.String password) ` of `PooledDataSource`. See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/PooledDataSource.html You can also access these Exceptions via JMX.

Comment: oh, and please upgrade to c3p0-0.9.5. 0.9.1.x is very old now.

Comment: Thank you Steve Waldman, that's exactly what I was looking for. Kind of dumb I did not notice that myself. Regarding the second comment, I cannot control the version being used...